# Code School Challenge JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and I found Code School so I am taking their course to learn it. I am completing one of the Challenges and this is the Challenge presented:

> Find all the window seats (a & d in first class, and a & f in economy) using any tools necessary.

Here is the code they provide:

```
<div id="seating_chart">
  <ul id="first_class">
    <li id="row_1">
      <ul>
        <li class="premium a"></li>
        <li class="premium b"></li>
        <li class="aisle"></li>
        <li class="premium c"></li>
        <li class="premium d"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="row_2">
      <ul>
        <li class="premium a"></li>
        <li class="premium b"></li>
        <li class="aisle"></li>
        <li class="premium c"></li>
        <li class="premium d"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="economy_class">
    <li id="row_3">
      <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="c"></li>
        <li class="aisle"></li>
        <li class="d"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>
        <li class="f"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="row_4">
      <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="c"></li>
        <li class="aisle"></li>
        <li class="d"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>
        <li class="f"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="row_5">
      <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="c"></li>
        <li class="aisle"></li>
        <li class="d"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>
        <li class="f"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="row_6">
      <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="c"></li>
        <li class="aisle"></li>
        <li class="d"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>
        <li class="f"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is what I came up with:

```
$('#first_class > li > ul > li.premium.a, li.premium.d, #economy_class >li > ul> li.a, li.f');
```

Now this code worked but I am wondering if there was an easier/better way to accomplish the Challenge? I want to learn as much as possible so my code is clean and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your answer has successfully found the elements you are looking for. It makes it hard for your team mates (in a real world project) to understand what you have done, and even for yourself this is hard to maintain.

What if the spec you were given was wrong (common) or has changed? (common) - on a large project this code: `$('#first_class > li > ul > li.premium.a, li.premium.d, #economy_class >li > ul> li.a, li.f');` will take you far longer to debug in my opinion compared to something like:

```
var $seating_chart = $('#seating_chart');
var $first_class = $seating_chart.find('#first_class');
var $first_class_window_seats = $first_class.find('.a, .d');
var $economy_class = $seating_chart.find('#economy_class');
var $economy_class_window_seats = $economy_class.find('.a, .f');
```

Now, when we want to further process the elements that we have found - we know exactly what they are for, and I think this code helps my fellow team mates understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks this was a great answer, my solution to the challenge was definitely confusing to me. With a lot more practice hopefully I can come up with code that is easier to maintain and comprehend.

Answer (score 6):

```
var firstOne  = $('#first_class').find('.a, .b'),
    secondOne = $('#economy_class').find('.a, .f'),
    both      = firstOne.add(secondOne);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDE97/)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can simply select the first and last `<li>` element in the `<ul>` elements:

```
/* Select window seats in first class. */
$('#first_class ul ul li:first-child, #first_class ul ul li:last-child');
```

As for your selector, you don't need to use carats. The `>` symbol will select only direct element descendants, but it'd be more flexible if you just did this:

```
$('#first_class li.a, #first_class li.d, #economy_class li.a, #economy_class li.f');
```

So this says "find any `<li>` element with the class `.a` that's a child of `#first_class`", and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fc = $('#first_class li').filter('.a, .d');
var ec = $('#economy_class li').filter('.a, .f');
var all = fc.add(ec);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var all = $('#first_class.d, #economy_class.f, .a');
```